Showing that $\mathbb{Q} [x,y] / (xy)$ is not a free $\mathbb{Q} [x,y]$-module
I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{Q} [x,y] / (xy)$ is not a free $\mathbb{Q} [x,y]$-module. Does the following seem like a complete solution? Just checking that my understanding of things is correct.
If $\mathbb{Q} [x,y] \langle X \rangle \approx \mathbb{Q} [x,y] / (xy) $, then
$z \in X$ maps to some element under the isomorphism $\varphi$. Now
$0 = xy \varphi(z) = \varphi (xyz)$, so since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism,
$xyz = 0$. But this is only possible if $z=0$. As $z \in X$ was arbitrary, we have
that $\langle X \rangle = \{ 0 \}$, but $\mathbb{Q} [x,y] / (xy) \not \approx \{0\}$. Contradiction.

You forgot the word "free"

Without the adjective "free", $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(xy)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$-module. So, please add the adjective "free" before "$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$-module" in both the title and the body.

This site is not a proof checking machine. Please check out the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

I fixed the tags and also added the missing "free" in title and body (SEO). So what Geoffrey already mentioned.
